# Sweetalert AJAX fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I tried implementing SweetAlert2 to my code,
I tried to call a function from the trigger button unsuccessfully.

any idea how to fix this code in order for it to work?

```
    $(".delete").click(function () {

                    swal({

                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                        type: 'warning',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
                    }).then(function () {
                 delete_post($(this).attr("id"));

                        swal(
                            'Deleted!',
                            'Your file has been deleted.',
                            'success'
                        )


                })

            })
        });
```

the called function:

```
  function delete_post(id) { 
            var info = {"delete_post_id":id};
            $.post('index.php',
                info
            ).done(function( response )  {
                if(response["error"]) {
                    $('#error').html(response["error"]);
                }else{
                    window.location = "index.php";
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: delete_post is not called?

Comment: yes it just skip the delete @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt

Comment: What does your response output? Call, delete_post before the success swal(). Also, my eyes burn from the missing semi-colons!

Comment: And is there any error in the console?

Comment: No errors on the console, it just skips the delete @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt

Comment: what missing semi-colons? @cnorthfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Halil said, it's because of `this` in your callback from the alert, `this` does not refer to your button in the callback, it refers to the callback function itself.

Assign the id to a variable before you display the alert so that you can use it in the callback like so:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {

  console.log('Delete button has been clicked...');

  // get the id
  var id = $(this).attr("id"));

  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(function() {

    console.log('Confirm button clicked...');

    // use the id we declared earlier
    delete_post(id);

    swal(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    );

  });

});

function delete_post(id) {

  console.log('Deleting post...', id);

  var info = {
    "delete_post_id": id
  };

  $.post('index.php', info)
    .done(function(response) {

      console.log('Completed request...', response);

      if (response["error"]) {

        $('#error').html(response["error"]);

      } else {

        window.location = "index.php";

      }

    });
}
```

I also added some console.log debugging so you can see what's going on when you run it in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

type `console.info(this);` before then this row :

```
delete_post($(this).attr("id"));
```

i think `this` is your function in then.

Comment: this should be a comment, it's not an answer to the question

Comment: i am new in this site. i can not add comment.
and i will never can add comment if you continue to click to minus button.

Comment: yes, but there is a reason for that :-) and it's not that newcomers should post their comments as answers